# How to verify an element exists within a unnamed table

Tags: cucumber, watir

I wish to verify that when I am on a certain page that a certain class exists. The class is contained in a table which is named voucher. Problem is there are many tables with the name voucher on this page. :-(

Normally to find elements I do something like:

`assert @browser.image(:class, "class1").exists?`

But as this is contained in the 1 of the voucher tables it means it can't find the element. I need a way to identify the table that the elements exists within.

Considering the fact that there are multiple tables named the same, how can I do this?

(btw - it is my intention to get unique names on the different tables but I need to get a solution to this problem first!)

Comment: How would you recognize the correct table manually?

Comment: I can verify the presence of the element by text. For example -  if I select certain options prior to this page I should then see option A and not option b or c. I

Comment: I can write a step that just checks to ensure that the correct text is present and another step to ensure that the text that shouldn't be there is not present. I can do this easily enough but I thought there would a better more elegant solution.

Comment: "ensure that the correct text is present" sounds like a perfectly elegant solution.